# Scaling Docker containers in Rancher with different but persistent volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rancher

I'm currently trying to bridge the gap between persistent, but unique volumes while scaling containers with Rancher (alternatively Docker Compose, since this is more of an abstract question).

Take as an example a Minecraft server, I have a Service defined in Rancher/Compose which uses a named volume as its data/world directory (e.g. -v minecraft_data:/data where the Minecraft image loads its world files from this /data directory). The reason I'm using such a named volume, is that I want it to persist between service upgrades (e.g. I'm changing the image version, or want to change some environment variables), which would not be possible with an anonymous volume.

Now when trying to scale up my service, I'm either getting multiple containers accessing the same data (not good for many use cases), or losing the service upgradeability when using anonymous volumes.

Are there any tools, best practices or patterns that might help with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In current versions of rancher (v1.4 at this time) [storage drivers](http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/v1.4/en/rancher-services/storage-service/) can be plugged in at the environment infrastructure level. This allows you to create volumes that are scoped at the environment, stack, or container.

For your use case, it sounds like per-container scope is what you need. Using `rancher-compose` you do something like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  foo:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
    - bar:/var/lib/storage
    command: /bin/sh -c 'while true; do sleep 500; done'
volumes:
  bar:
    per_container: true
```

Then, `rancher-compose up -d` will create the stack and service with one container and a unique volume. `rancher scale foo=2` will create another container with its own volume, etc. You can also specify volume storage drivers for each volume like `rancher-ebs` or `rancher-nfs` with their respective options.

Comment: Is this also possible to do in the Rancher GUI? From reading the volume scope documentation (http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/v1.4/en/rancher-services/storage-service/), it seems I have to install a storage driver, other than simple, local storage to get the option.

Comment: You can create environment-scoped volumes from the GUI after you add the driver from the catalog. To get per-container, it seems to only be an option in the compose syntax so far (as of 1.4)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to have difference instances of the entire project. `scale` implies identical clones, but if they have different data, they are not identical.

Instead of using scale, I would start different instances with different project names: https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/#multiple-isolated-environments-on-a-single-host

Comment: That is probably true, I just hoped there would be a way to easily automate this in the same way that scale works (i.e. the containers and volumes get a consecutive number). I can imagine it would look somewhat messy in the stack quite soon creating a new service for each container needed.